# In jQuery Mobile, how do I prevent a link becoming a button in the header or footer?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement the new jQuery Mobile Alpha 2. Currently, any link within `data-role="header"` or `data-role="footer"` becomes a button. Is there a way to disable that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The new version of jQuery Mobile (1.3pre) has fixed this issue.
From the manual:

> "If you need to to create a header
>   that doesn't follow the default
>   configuration, simply wrap your custom
>   styled markup in a container div
>   inside the header container and the
>   plugin won't apply the automatic
>   button logic so you can write custom
>   styles for laying out the content in
>   your header."

If you [grab the source from github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile) it will work.

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is to use a data-role="none" attribute:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <a href="somewhere" data-role="none">Not a jQM button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Example based on answer by @gleitz:

```
<div  data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <div> <!-- new bit -->
          <a href='nextpageetc.php'>Not a button </a>
      </div> <!-- new bit -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering too! I've tried adding `rel="external"` to the link, but this seems to be ignored for headers an footers.

@naugtur: I'm refreshing it with ajax now. thanks for the tip. But I still hope this issue gets fixed for the next release (can't wait; I'm already using a package from the development branch :D ).

@update: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/issue/714 (I accidentally closed the ticket and couldn't reopen it again -_-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any direct option to do it in HTML, but I admit - I didn't search for it much.

You can get the desired effect in one of those ways:

1. remove a css class `button` and/or other needed
2. don't add them in html - insert them links when DOM is ready and they will not be changed to buttons.

The first method is better, because it degrades for browsers with bad JS support.